Changing the integration limits of a triple integral
I have a triple integral of the form
$$
\int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \int_0^{t_1} dt_3\ f(t_1,t_2,t_3)
$$
and I want to transform it to the form
$$
\int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \int_0^{t_2} dt_3\ g(t_1,t_2,t_3) \ ,
$$
so one of the original upper limits to $t_1$ transforms to an upper limit to $t_2$ (I guess it is also valid to transform it to $t_3$ and the relabel variables). However, I do not know how to proceed with such transformation. I also wrote $g$ instead of the original $f$, assuming that such transformation might generate additional factors that I could later absorb into a new function.

It seems that it would be sufficient if we would have a method to do it for just this double integral:
$$
\int_0^{t_1} \!\!\!\!\! dt_2 \int_0^{t_1}\!\!\!\!\!  dt_3\ f(t_2,t_3) = 
\int_0^{t_1} \!\!\!\!\! dt_2 \int_0^{t_2}\!\!\!\!\!  dt_3\ g(t_2,t_3)
$$
which could then be extended to your triple integral by integrating over $t_1$ without further changes. And for the double integral we can more easily draw integration regions on paper. Instead of a square integration region $[0,t_1]\times [0,t_1]$ you want to integrate only over a triangle that contains half of it.
You'll find that it works if you define:
$$ g(t_2,t_3) = f(t_2,t_3) + f(t_3,t_2) $$
It is not possible to keep only $f(t_2,t_3)$ with some cleverly chosen multiplicative factor, because we then could make arbitrarily large changes to the function in the integration region you left out (the other triangle), without seeing it in the result.
For the triple integral the conclusions are the same. There it will work with:
$$ g(t_1,t_2,t_3) = f(t_1,t_2,t_3) + f(t_1,t_3,t_2). $$
